# Check if parentname == main or how else to prevent my threads to spawn new threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say i have 2 scripts, user_script.py and thread_manager.py:
user_script.py:
Is written by a user who knows basic python and does something (litterally anything).

thread_manager.py:
Is written by me and implements basic safety features, for example a physical emergency stop button.
This code basically implements a sandbox for user_script.py to run in so it can't do much harm to the outside wolrd.

For this to work and be as easy to use as possible, thread_manager.py is imported on the first line of code into user_script.py. No other modifications aside that import should be made to user_script.py!

Right now, my code results in a loop, where the user_script.py imports thread_manager.py, which again imports user_script.py and so on.

This is the code of user_script.py:

```
import thread_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("If we see this, our mission failed!")

else:
    print("Mission accomplished! Or is it?!")
```

This is the code of thread_manager.py:

```
import threading

class Restart_with_Safety_Features(Exception):
    pass

class ThreadManager(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ThreadName):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ThreadName = ThreadName
        
    def run(self):
        if self.ThreadName == "MAIN":
            print("start MAIN")
            self.MAIN()
            
        if self.ThreadName == "user_script":
            print("start user_script")
            self.user_script()
            
#HERE FOLLOW DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS THAT BECOME THREADS:    
    def MAIN(self):
        print("MAIN started")
        userScript = ThreadManager("user_script")
        userScript.start()
        userScript.join()
        print("MAIN finished")
        
    def user_script(self):
        print("user_script started")
        import user_script #this is the main thing we want to execute
        print("user_script finished")

# this causes a loop that could be prevent with an if __parentname__ == '__main__'
ThreadManager("MAIN").start()
raise Restart_with_Safety_Features()
```

Comment: Uh. Why does user_script.py import the thread_manager? Since it's thread_manager that is "main" file, then it should import or otherwise find and run the user's file, not the other way around. You don't use anything from thread_manager in user_script, so the import is not needed - and just removing it will fix the looping

Comment: The approach of importing thread_manager into the user_script is an "ease of use" approach. I have the situation where several people have created several scripts they work with (for a python-script based lab automation) and asked me for a solution that works with minimal changes to the scripts and how the users interact with them. f.e. it is easier to copy paste one line of code into a script you know and already worked with than handle a thread manager or an interface for the occasion you need some safety implementations (which is just sometimes).

Comment: But those scripts don't even use anything from it. They don't need to import it (and they shouldn't). They just need to be importable by you - you're managing them, they shouldn't care whether they're being run directly, in a subprocess, in a thread, in whatever - they should just do their job. As I said, the thread_manager is your "main" file - no one should import the main file, it's the one that runs everything else

Comment: OK, the Short reason I try to do it that way is: The People i write the code for want it that way.The code is meant to function like a sandbox (actually, the user script is executed in a subprocess that can be killed at the push of a button, but that detail is not relevant to solve the problem at hand)

Comment: This still doesn't explain why those user scripts need to import your file. Seriously. I have a similar setup (I get a path supplied from external system through rest api, then I run it), most of them are subprocesses - and subprocess doesn't care what actually runs it. Again: the script shouldn't care whether it's run directly or via your thread manager, as long as dependencies etc are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer to my Question is rather simple, as always:
Instead of checking if a Parentmodule (user_script.py in my case) is run as **main**, it is sufficient to check the name of the first module on the "call-stack".

Basically: If thread_manager.py is run from user_script.py, user_script.py is first on the "call-stack". If in the second turn, user_script.py is run in a thread by thread_manager.py, the first entry on the "call-stack" is threading.py.

I used traceback to solve this, but inspect should work too.
Here is my code (replace the last two lines of code from thread_manager.py with this):

```
pathes_stack = traceback.extract_stack()      #get Paths of locations from where the traceback function is called
path_to_fktcall = pathes_stack[0].filename    #choose Path and format
caller_script = ''.join(path_to_fktcall.rsplit('\\', 1)[1:]) #only keep the filename

if caller_script != "threading.py":
    ThreadManager("MAIN").start()
    raise Restart_with_Safety_Features()
```

My appologies if i did not use the right terms or misspelled something, i am relatively new to python. Corrections are very welcome!